# Continuously ask for a user input

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have two available options for a user to input, and what I am trying to accomplish is if the user does not enter either of the inputs the program will continuously ask them again until they enter a valid one. Here is the code right now

```
String userLIB = user_input.next();
    if (userLIB.contentEquals(UBC.acro)){
        printDetails(UBC);
    } else {
        if (userLIB.contentEquals(ORL.acro)){
            printDetails(ORL);
        } else {
            while (!userLIB.contentEquals(UBC.acro) || !userLIB.contentEquals(ORL.acro)){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a break to keep the code from looping the "Invalid input" indefinetly but it just ends the program right now which isn't what I want to happen. Is there a way to make the program go back to the start of the if statement?

Comment: You should be looping over all the code shouldn't you? Evidently you know how to use loops. Have you tried using one to go back to the top of the program?

Comment: Like @Carcigenicate suggests, wrap your code into another loop but don't forget to have an "exit" option unless you're fine with brutally stop the program

Comment: `while` with immediate `break` behaves as `if`.

Comment: How would I go about putting another loop into this code? Would I start with another if statement?

Comment: @MemeBoi I've added an answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @MemeBoi please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking your code when the Invalid input condition is met.
Do as following,

```
String userLIB = "";
do {
    userLIB = user_input.next();
    if (userLIB.contentEquals(UBC.acro)){
        printDetails(UBC);
    } else if (userLIB.contentEquals(ORL.acro)) {
        printDetails(ORL);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again!");
    }
} while (!userLIB.contentEquals(UBC.acro) || !userLIB.contentEquals(ORL.acro));
```

This, tries to get the only 2 possible inputs and terminate the loop.
Else will loop again and again, until the required input is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of @Carcigenicate, I put a while loop outside of the whole code and then put a userLIB = user_input.next(); inside of the incorrect if statement. Also thanks to @Sridhar for giving an answer that also works